# Cropper JS dont work correctly in mobile browsers. HELP PLS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, cropperjs

Cropper JS 1.15.3 the latest version.

In PC all work normally, but on every mobile browser, there is one problem - my cropper sometimes works, sometimes dont.

In lucky day it can works two or three times in a row, in bad day it can dont work at all...

I tried to resize pictures to 1023px. (on server and without)

I cant find the solution to my problem.

Im working on a project about 3 months and cant handle this problem.

```
import { el, setChildren } from 'redom';
import { createCardApp } from './card';
import savePhoto from '../assets/images/savePhoto.svg';
import closePhoto from '../assets/images/closePhoto.svg';
import rechoosePhoto from '../assets/images/rechoosePhoto.svg';
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
import { updateCard, updateUser } from './API';
import { barLine } from './barLine';

let cropper = null;
console.log(cropper);

export function createChangeUserDataPage(obj, PHOTO, AVATAR_DEFAULT) {
  const header = el(
    'header.header.sm-offset',
    el('div.bar'),
    el('div.container.header__container', [
      el('div.message__btn-wrap', el('button.js-backBtn.btn.message__btn')),
      el('h2.header__title-comp', 'Личные данные'),
    ])
  );

  const main = el(
    'main.main',
    el('div.container', [
      el('div.avatar.hidden-avatar', [
        el('canvas.noborder', {
          id: 'cropped-image',
          width: '500',
          height: '500',
        }),
      ]),
      el('div.avatar-photo-container', [
        el('div.card-ph', [
          el(
            'div.card-front',
            PHOTO === null ? `${AVATAR_DEFAULT}` : el('img', { src: PHOTO })
          ),
        ]),
      ]),
      el('button.footer__btn.btn.active-btn.avatar-btn', 'Изменить фото'),
      el('form.data.main-comp', [
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Фамилия'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Имя'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Отчество'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Ваша должность'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Мобильный телефон'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Email'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Домашний телефон'),
        ]),
        el('label.inp-wrap', [
          el('input.data__input.input', { type: 'text' }),
          el('span.inp-placeholder', 'Личный сайт'),
        ]),
      ]),
    ])
  );

  const footer = el(
    'footer.footer',
    el('div.container', el('button.footer__btn.btn.active-btn', 'Сохранить'))
  );

  const modal = el('div.blur', [
    el(
      'div.close-photo-container',
      el('button.btn', el('img', { src: closePhoto }))
    ),
    el('.cropper__size.circle', [el('img#selected-image')]),
    el('div.buttons-container', [
      el(
        'button.btn.rechoose-btn',
        el('img', { src: rechoosePhoto }),
        'Выбрать другое'
      ),
      el('button.btn.cropper__btn', el('img', { src: savePhoto })),
    ]),
  ]);

  setChildren(document.body, [header, main, footer, modal]);

  returnPage();
  activateInputs();
  fillInputs(obj);
  closePhotoChoose();
  chooseAnotherPhoto();
  crop();
  validateInputs();
  emailInput();
}

function returnPage() {
  const BTN = document.querySelector('.js-backBtn');

  BTN.addEventListener('click', () => {
    createCardApp();
  });
}

function activateInputs() {
  const INPUTS = document.querySelectorAll('.data__input');

  INPUTS.forEach((e) => {
    const SPAN = e.parentNode.children[1];
    e.addEventListener('input', () => {
      SPAN.classList.add('_active');
      if (e.value.length === 0) {
        SPAN.classList.remove('_active');
      }
    });
  });
}

function fillInputs(obj) {
  const INPUTS = document.querySelectorAll('.data__input');

  INPUTS[0].value = obj.Surname;
  INPUTS[0].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  INPUTS[1].value = obj.FirstName;
  INPUTS[1].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  INPUTS[4].value = obj.Phone;
  INPUTS[4].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  INPUTS[5].value = obj.Email;
  INPUTS[5].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');

  if (obj.LastName) {
    INPUTS[2].value = obj.LastName;
    INPUTS[2].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  }
  if (obj.JobTitle) {
    INPUTS[3].value = obj.JobTitle;
    INPUTS[3].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  }
  if (obj.HomePhone) {
    INPUTS[6].value = obj.HomePhone;
    INPUTS[6].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  }
  if (obj.Site) {
    INPUTS[7].value = obj.Site;
    INPUTS[7].parentNode.children[1].classList.add('_active');
  }
}

function closePhotoChoose() {
  const BTN = document.querySelector('.close-photo-container');

  BTN.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.blur').style.display = 'none';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
  });
}

function choosePhoto() {
  let selectedImage = document.getElementById('selected-image');
  let croppedCanvas = document.getElementById('cropped-image');

  if (croppedCanvas.classList.contains('fullfilled')) {
    croppedCanvas.classList.remove('fullfilled');
  }
  croppedCanvas.classList.remove('null');
  let fileInput = document.createElement('input');
  fileInput.type = 'file';
  fileInput.accept = 'image/*';

  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('.blur').style.display = 'block';
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

      let file = e.target.files[0];
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (event) {
        let imageUrl = event.target.result;
        selectedImage.src = imageUrl;
        console.log('l');
        if (cropper) {
          cropper.replace(imageUrl);
        } else {
          cropper = new Cropper(selectedImage, {
            cropBoxMovable: false,
            aspectRatio: 1,
            autoCropArea: 1,
            viewMode: 2,
            cropBoxResizable: false,
            rotatable: false,
            zoomOnTouch: true,
            zoomOnWheel: true,
            minZoom: 0.1,
            maxZoom: 1,
            dragMode: 'move',
            checkOrientation: false,
          });
        }
      };

      reader.onerror = function (event) {
        alert(event.target.error);
        console.error('Ошибка чтения файла:', event.target.error);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      alert('Неверный файл');
    }
  });

  fileInput.click();
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (e.target.files.length > 0) {
      document.querySelector('.blur').style.display = 'block';
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
      alert('bad');
      return;
    }
  });
}

function chooseAnotherPhoto() {
  const BTN = document.querySelector('.rechoose-btn');
  const MODAL = document.querySelector('.blur');

  BTN.addEventListener('click', () => {
    MODAL.style.display = 'none';
    choosePhoto();
  });
}

function crop() {
  let croppedCanvas = document.getElementById('cropped-image');
  const btn = document.querySelector('.cropper__btn');
  const chooseBtn = document.querySelector('.avatar-btn');
  const NEXT_BUTTON = document.querySelectorAll('.footer__btn')[1];

  chooseBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    choosePhoto();
  });

  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (cropper !== null && !croppedCanvas.classList.contains('fullfilled')) {
      let croppedImage = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
      let croppedContext = croppedCanvas.getContext('2d');
      croppedContext.clearRect(0, 0, croppedCanvas.width, croppedCanvas.height);
      croppedContext.drawImage(
        croppedImage,
        0,
        0,
        croppedCanvas.width,
        croppedCanvas.height
      );
      // document.querySelector('.cropper-container').remove();
      croppedCanvas.classList.add('fullfilled');

      document.querySelector('.blur').style.display = 'none';
      document.body.style.overflow = 'visible';
      document.querySelector('.avatar').style.display = 'flex';
      document.querySelector('.avatar-photo-container').style.display = 'none';
    }
  });

  barLine(NEXT_BUTTON);

  NEXT_BUTTON.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const INPUTS = document.querySelectorAll('.data__input');
    if (INPUTS[0].value.length < 2) {
      INPUTS[0].classList.remove('_cor');
      INPUTS[0].classList.add('_del');
    } else {
      INPUTS[0].classList.remove('_del');
      INPUTS[0].classList.add('_cor');
    }
    if (INPUTS[1].value.length < 2) {
      INPUTS[1].classList.remove('_cor');
      INPUTS[1].classList.add('_del');
    } else {
      INPUTS[1].classList.remove('_del');
      INPUTS[1].classList.add('_cor');
    }
    if (emailValidation(INPUTS[5].value)) {
      INPUTS[5].classList.remove('_del');
      INPUTS[5].classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      INPUTS[5].classList.remove('_cor');
      INPUTS[5].classList.add('_del');
    }
    if (
      (INPUTS[4].value.length > 10 &&
        /^[0-9\s]+$/g.test(INPUTS[4].value.trim()) &&
        INPUTS[4].value.length < 12) ||
      INPUTS[4].value.length === 0
    ) {
      INPUTS[4].classList.remove('_del');
      INPUTS[4].classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      INPUTS[4].classList.remove('_cor');
      INPUTS[4].classList.add('_del');
    }

    let count = 0;

    INPUTS.forEach(async (e) => {
      if (e.classList.contains('_cor')) {
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
        if (count < 4) {
          return;
        } else {
          const img = document.getElementById('cropped-image');
          const fullImg = document.getElementById('selected-image');

          window.scrollTo({
            top: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth',
          });

          if (img.classList.contains('fullfilled')) {
            const data = {
              surName: INPUTS[0].value.trim(),
              name: INPUTS[1].value.trim(),
              lastName: INPUTS[2].value.trim(),
              phone: INPUTS[4].value.trim(),
              photo: fullImg.src !== '' ? fullImg.src : null,
              crop: img.toDataURL('image/png'),
            };
            const dataSec = {
              CID: localStorage.getItem('CID'),
              photo: fullImg.src !== '' ? fullImg.src : null,
              crop: img.toDataURL('image/png'),
              email: INPUTS[5].value.trim(),
              surName: INPUTS[0].value.trim(),
              name: INPUTS[1].value.trim(),
              lastName: INPUTS[2].value.trim(),
              phone: INPUTS[4].value.trim(),
              homePhone: INPUTS[6].value.trim(),
              site: INPUTS[7].value.trim(),
              job: INPUTS[3].value.trim(),
            };
            const update1 = updateCard(dataSec);
            const update = updateUser(data);
            const [l, k] = await Promise.all([update1, update]);
            console.log(l, k);
          } else {
            const data = {
              surName: INPUTS[0].value.trim(),
              name: INPUTS[1].value.trim(),
              lastName: INPUTS[2].value.trim(),
              phone: INPUTS[4].value.trim(),
            };
            const dataSec = {
              CID: localStorage.getItem('CID'),
              email: INPUTS[5].value.trim(),
              surName: INPUTS[0].value.trim(),
              name: INPUTS[1].value.trim(),
              lastName: INPUTS[2].value.trim(),
              phone: INPUTS[4].value.trim(),
              homePhone: INPUTS[6].value.trim(),
              site: INPUTS[7].value.trim(),
              job: INPUTS[3].value.trim(),
            };
            const update1 = updateCard(dataSec);
            const update = updateUser(data);
            const [l, k] = await Promise.all([update1, update]);
            console.log(l, k);
          }
          createCardApp();
          cropper = null;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function validateInputs() {
  const INPUTS = document.querySelectorAll('.data__input');

  INPUTS.forEach((e) => {
    if (e !== INPUTS[4] && e !== INPUTS[5]) {
      e.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
        e.target.style.borderColor = 'rgba(41, 98, 255, 1)';
        if (e.target.value.length === 0) {
          e.target.style.borderColor = '#b0bec5';
        }
      });
    }
  });

  INPUTS[0].addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
      e.target.classList.remove('_del');
      e.target.classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove('_cor');
      e.target.classList.add('_del');
    }
  });

  INPUTS[1].addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value.length > 2) {
      e.target.classList.remove('_del');
      e.target.classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove('_cor');
      e.target.classList.add('_del');
    }
  });

  INPUTS[4].addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (
      e.target.value.length > 10 &&
      /^[0-9\s]+$/g.test(e.target.value.trim()) &&
      e.target.value.length < 12
    ) {
      e.target.classList.remove('_del');
      e.target.classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      e.target.classList.remove('_cor');
      e.target.classList.add('_del');
    }
  });
}

function emailInput() {
  const email = document.querySelectorAll('.data__input')[5];

  email.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (emailValidation(email.value.trim())) {
      email.classList.remove('_del');
      email.classList.add('_cor');
    } else {
      email.classList.remove('_cor');
      email.classList.add('_del');
    }
  });
}

function emailValidation(value) {
  const EMAIL_REGEXP = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)$/;

  return EMAIL_REGEXP.test(value);
}
```